# Filenames with "!" and "$" being missed by preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, trim

I have a script which filters files by filename, for example if the filename contains "(Japan)" it gets moved to a "Removed" directory.

```
<?php
$gameList = trim(shell_exec("ls -1"));
$gameArray = explode("\n", $gameList);

shell_exec('mkdir -p Removed');

// Do this magic for every file
foreach ($gameArray as $thisGame)
{
    if (!$thisGame) continue;
    // Probably already been removed
    if (!file_exists($thisGame)) continue;

    $niceName = trim(preg_replace('%[\(|\[].*%', '', $thisGame));

    // Non-Engish speaking countries e.g. (France) or (Japan)
    if (preg_match('%\((Asia|Austria|Brazil|China|Denmark|Finland|France|Germany|Greece|Hungary|Israel|Italy|Japan|Japan, Asia|Korea|Netherlands|Norway|Poland|Portugal|Russia|Scandinavia|Spain|Sweden)\)%', $thisGame))
    {
        echo "{$thisGame} is a foreign language release. Moved to Removed folder.\n";
        shell_exec("mv \"{$thisGame}\" Removed/");
        continue;
    }
```

... The script goes on from here

While this is working, it seems to be missing specific files:

```
...Iru! (Japan).zip
```

and

```
Quiz$Millionaire - Waku Waku Party (Japan).zip
```

to name a couple. I guess this is to do with their funny characters. I don't think it's the exclamation mark (!) as other files with it are being filtered correctly, so is it the period? (.) And on the second file I guess it's the dollar sign ($).

Any advice on how I can fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: is it possibly because I am using Cygdrive? I am getting `Quiz$Millionaire (Japan) (v1.0).zip is a foreign language release. Moved to Removed folder.` but then an error: `mv: cannot stat 'Quiz (Japan) (v1.0).zip': No such file or directory` - It looks as if it's forgetting the name after the dollar symbol!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing shell commands directly you need to escape shell metacharacters. Put this somewhere before last `shell_exec`:

```
$thisGame = escapeshellcmd($thisGame);
```

Comment: Thanks - So how would I go about fixing? I have several filenames with "Gamename (Japan)" which get filtered perfectly fine :-/

Comment: Why do you need that `preg_replace`?

Comment: I have just found a clue as to why it's not working: I am getting this output: 

`Quiz$Millionaire (Japan) (v1.0).zip is a foreign language release. Moved to Removed folder.`

`mv: cannot stat 'Quiz (Japan) (v1.0).zip': No such file or directory`

So everything after the dollar sign is being left out...

Comment: the `$niceName` is called later in the script I think!

Comment: Thanks! Where abouts should I put it? It needs to go in after $thisGame has been defined but if I put it anywhere after it seems to stop the filter working for every other game :-(

Comment: This doesn't work. When using `$thisGame = escapeshellcmd($thisGame);` it stops matching anything!

Comment: When you do `escapeshellcmd` it tries to escape characters that have a special meaning in shell. Parenthesis is one of them. So you should act accordingly with modifying your regex. Check it here https://3v4l.org/XeiaF

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I modify my regex to correct this? I'm really sorry I have no idea :-(

Comment: My pleasure. I made the correction in demo I provided.

Comment: Did you see the live demo? It's passed and `echo` statement within `if` is executed.

Comment: It's matching, but it's still not successfully moving the file with `shell_exec("mv \"{$thisGame}\" Removed/");`

Comment: Please echo `$thisGame` in your side and show me the output.

Comment: it echo's on the line above the mv error: https://i.imgur.com/UW5qeT8.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173654/discussion-between-unluckyforsome-and-revo).